# opengl glProgramUniform___() causes program to crash

Tags: opengl, uniform

I'm trying to apply transforms within my vertex shader in VisualStudio2012 using visual c++ but when I try to use

`glProgramUniform1f()`

or any other variant of the glProgramUniform function it just crashes and gives me this error
`Unhandled exception at 0x7513C9F5 in Lab1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000000.`

I tried running the code on a different machine and it runs fine, is there anything obvious that could be causing this?

I can't imagine that it's my computer not being able to handle the graphics manipulation as I have a nvidia 650m

Comment: Different drivers might be more or less robust regarding to (OpenGL) usage errors. An incorrect OpenGL command could simply be ignored on driver/system A while it causes a crash on driver/system b. Remember that drivers are written for performance and do most likely not perform intensive error checking or the like. I like to use gDebugger to catch OpenGL errors, that way I don't have to pollute my code with glGetErrors.

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a look and see if it can shed some light on my problem, and hopefully a solution

Comment: This problem is related to either your driver and/or extension loading code not implementing `GL_EXT_direct_state_access` or `GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects`. You will have to use `glUseProgram (...)` to establish the currently bound GLSL program and then set your uniforms in lieu of either of these extensions. This applies to Intel, Mesa and Apple's OpenGL implementations more than any others, if you want to make your code portable while using `glProgramUniform__ (...)` you will have to write two code paths, sadly :-\

Comment: Thanks, I had the solution but no reason for why it wouldn't work, I'll have a look into what you've said to try to understand it better. Fortunately this code doesn't need to be portable yet as for now I'm just learning

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, there are two ways this can be done

`glProgramUniform1f()`

which didn't work for me, and

```
glUseProgram(shaderProgramID);

glUniform1f(transformLoc, 0.5);
```

which did work